# model builder add one column more?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, ef-model-builder

I use EF code first.

It's my modelbuilder

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Market>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.State)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.StateId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

and State Class :

```
public class State
{
    public State()
    {
        Markets = new HashSet<Market>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public string StateName { get; set; }

    // navigation property

    public virtual ICollection<Market> Markets  { get; set; }
}
```

and Market class :

```
public class Market
{
    [Key]
    public int MarketId { get; set; }

    public string MarketName { get; set; }

    public int StateId { get; set; }

    // navigation property

    public virtual State State { get; set; }

}
```

Of course I remove extra code.

Problem is when I use this code , an State_StateId column add to my Market table in database, and when I do not use modelbuilder an error occurred with message loop code and ... (I say that I remove extra code), so how can I use code first without this "State_StateId" extra column.

excuse me for bad english writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove `State_StateId`  column set the configuration completely like the code below and don't let `WithMany` empty:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Market>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.State)
        .WithMany(p => p.Markets)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.StateId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Or you can just remove the Fluent API configuration and let EF use the default configuration convention and will set all tables, primary keys, foreign keys and column name for you.

Comment: Thank you for help, It was useful.